# Swift add action if user click back button

Tags: swift, stack, warnings

I successfully detect if user clicked on back button by using the following code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    let viewControllers: NSArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as! NSArray
    if viewControllers.indexOfObject(self) == NSNotFound {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

but I get the following warning:

> Cast from '[AnyObject]?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails

Is there a "neater" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `NSArray`, you should use the Swift array - `[UIViewController]`

**Fixed issue:**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as [UIViewController]

        if let index = find(viewControllers, self)
        {
            //your object exists in that is at index

        }
        else
        {
           //your object is not in the navigation controller
           self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        }

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

**Instead of `if let else`, you can use:**

```
if find(viewControllers, self) == nil
{
    //your object isnt in the viewControllers array

}
```

Comment: This will not work. In Swift, navigationController.viewControllers will always contain self.

Comment: There's a much simpler way than looking at the view controllers inside `viewWillDisappear`. Call `isBeingDismissed` inside `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue is that you are trying to cast to the objective-c array type, NSArray. Swift uses Array instead of NSArray/NSMutableArray. If you want to cast arrays in Swift, you have to specify the type of object inside the array. So the following code:

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as! [UIViewController]
```

casts it specifically as an Array (Swift array) of UIViewControllers. You can actually write it shorter and just have this:

```
let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as! [UIViewController]
```

Comment: I got `[UIViewController] does not have a member named 'indexOfObject'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
        if let index = find(viewControllers, self) {
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

    viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Using find() is more inline with Swift from my opinion. find() will return index of the element if found, nil otherwise.

Comment: I got `Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject]?,...`